# Route dispatcher in CherryPy not working

Tags: python, cherrypy

But when I load http://example.com/myblog/1/edit it continues to give me a 404 error. Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`blog/:entry_id/:action` -> `/blog/:entry_id/:action`